# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer SOLO las columnas que se actualizaron mediante TRIGGER de forma genérica? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

He visto preguntas del estilo, pero creo que no resuelven mi problema totalmente.
Dado el siguiente código del TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_employees_update
AFTER UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'employees';
    OPEN col_cursor;
      col_loop: LOOP
      FETCH col_cursor INTO col_name;
         IF col_cursor % NOTFOUND THEN LEAVE col_loop;
      END IF;
      IF OLD.col_name <=> NEW.col_name THEN
          -- la columna col_name ha sido actualizada (Aquí pondré otro código)
      END IF;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE col_cursor;
END;
```

Ahora bien, esto recorrerá columna por columna. No existe alguna forma que únicamente recorra las columnas actualizadas? Tampoco quiero que esté comparando todas las columnas para ver si se ha modificado o no ya que si luego agrego nuevas columnas tendré que modificar todos los TRIGGERS para que también se disparen al actualizar estas nuevas columnas.

Agradezco cualquier comentario
Gracias

También quiero evitar este tipo de código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_employees_update
AFTER UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.id <=> NEW.id THEN
    -- la columna id ha sido actualizada
END IF;

IF OLD.name <=> NEW.name THEN
    -- la columna name ha sido actualizada
END IF;

IF OLD.salary <=> NEW.salary THEN
    -- la columna salary ha sido actualizada
END IF;

IF OLD.department <=> NEW.department THEN
    -- la columna department ha sido actualizada
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: ¿Para qué es esto exactamente? Lo más viable sería quizá tener una tabla histórica y comparar la tabla actual con dicha tabla o bien llevando un control mediante la comparación del valor de cada columna, como muestras en tu segundo bloque de código. OJO, no sacrifiques el rendimiento en busca de un código que parece fácil a simple vista, pero que podría ser costoso.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @A.Cedano, simplemente lo que necesito es que si un usuario hace un `UPDATE` en la tabla X, quiero insertar en una tabla LOGS los cambios que ha hecho. Por ejemplo si de la tabla X modifica la columna name y department únicamente., Entonces en LOGS se insertaría siguiendo: `[ID, OLD, NEW, IDUSER]` => de forma que: `[1, NAMEANT, NAMENUEVO,  1]` y `[2, DEPANT, DEPNEW, 1]`. No sé si me explico bien. Si hubiera solo 2 columnas no tendría problema en hacerlo manualmente, comparar cuáles se han modificado e insertar de forma manual. Pero puede que agregue, borre columnas...